# No such entity for customer grid magento2

Tags: magento2.2.3

i face the issue in magento223 version after data migration for only customer data to magento223 setup migration was successfully completed.

but in admin login in all customer grid it shows like "No such entity." how to resolve this issue can any one help out for this ?

i also done with index:reindex command and cache:clean commange still not display.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**When you transfer the data the insert records on these specific records are automatically generated and tend to start at 1 and not 0.**

> I think this script work for you :-

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: this is already value set in my tables all value is same as you mention any other way ?

Comment: Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully or not ?

Comment: yes grid rebuilt successfully and the from customer data i do logged in via front end using the credential and it's successfully logged in in frontend but not display in backend side.

Comment: To debug this issue, please open the file

vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php

Comment: i debug the file also but nothing is desplayed and i debug the migrated customer data in that entry the store_id and website_id was change and i was update that value and index:reindex was also done still customer grid not came.

Answer (score 0):

In database table 'customer_entity' confirm website id with existing website if not match then change it and run below commands.

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:flush